# using sites/getAllSites will return all sites in multi-geo enabled tenant

Tags: sharepoint, graph, sharepoint-online

There is a new API in Graph called site/getAllSites will return every sites in the multi-geo enabled tenant or will return the Root Sites only or will the sites that are available in the current geo instance.